# Swagger includes 404 for all routes and controllers in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

Lately I added Swagger package to my app. Before that, I had specified global exception handlers via @RestControllerAdvice.

There, I handle exceptions like `NOT FOUND` like for the GET methods where resource specified by an ID is not found.

I have `ResourceControllers` and `RegistrationController` in my app.

The problem is that now all my endpoints and controllers has `NOT FOUND` included in the documentation. But it is not possible for POST endpoints to throw that exception (like in RegistrationController or some endpoints in ResourceController).

How can I exclude `NOT FOUND` error showing up in my docs for the POST methods?

Things I tried:

1. Explicitly defining @ApiResponses in Controllers - it does work but only if I disable global @ControllerAdvice

```
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "(OK) User created"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "(BAD REQUEST) Invalid data"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "422", description = "(UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY) Email already taken")
    })
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody @Valid RegisterFormDTO registerFormDTO) {
        User createdUser = userService.create(registerFormDTO);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new CreatedUserDTO(createdUser), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

2. Using @RequestMapping with a @ExceptionHandling in @RestContollerAdvice

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ConditionalOnExpression("#{request.method != 'POST'}")
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> resourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage(
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),
                new Date(),
                ex.getMessage(),
                null);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
/* *** */
```

Other approaches could be grouping ControllerAdvices for specific controller classes but it wouldn't work since it would require to extract POST methods from them somewhere else.